# elegant solution to nested else-if chains

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

In Python, is there a more elegant solution to the following nested else-if chain?

```
if interval == 1:
    a += 1
else:
    if interval == 2:
        b += 1
    else:
        if interval == 3:
            c += 1
        else:
            if interval == 4:
                d += 1
            else:
                if interval == 5:
                    e += 1
                else:
                    if interval == 6:
                        f += 1
```

Comment: Use `elif`, not `else`...

Answer (score 2):

```
if interval == 1:
    a += 1
elif interval == 2:
    b += 1
elif interval == 3:
    c += 1
elif interval == 4:
    d += 1
elif interval == 5:
    e += 1
elif interval == 6:
    f += 1
```

Of course, if you can extract `a`..`f` into a dictionary, like:

```
state = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0}
```

you can do

```
interval_to_state = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: "e", 6: "f"}
state[interval_to_state[interval]] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) instead of multiple variables:

```
#         a  b  c  d  e  f   # Index 0 are unused.
acc = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # OR  [0] * 7
if 1 <= interval <= 7:
    acc[interval] += 1
    # OR acc[interval - 1] += 1
    #    If you don't want to waste a slot in the list.
```

Comment: Or, `acc[interval - 1] += 1`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I added a comment in the code to mention it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a dictionary, with reverse lookup, like this

```
values = {name: 0 for name in "abcdef"}
indexes = {idx: name for idx, name in enumerate("abcdef", 1)}
values[indexes[interval]] += 1
```

Comment: Note `dict.fromkeys("abcdef", 0)`

Comment: @Veedrac Yup, but I find comprehension more readable than `fromkeys`